# How to Fire Asp.net Button Click of Remote Website

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

Please any one help me to fire Button Click Event of Remote site and after that get all html code of page

I know I can use HttpWebRequest to get all Data, but i don't know how to fire click event

I find this code:

```
 `HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url"); 

    httpRequest.Method = "POST"; 
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 


byte[] bytedata =  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(poststring);
    httpRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

    Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = 
    (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream =  httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (StreamReader reader = 
    new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
      string line;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        sb.Append(line);
      }
    }
```

`

Comment: You could use WatiN as a "crawler" or bot so to speak. It is normal used for acceptance testing but can easily have it go to a url and click the button based on its ID or class etc. http://watin.org/

Comment: Did you see the link http://watin.org/

Comment: if there is way by jquery to do that?

Comment: @user2678754- Create a webmethod to do it using WaitN and call that method from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

for click use jquery trigger http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

use it on your page load (registerStartupScript).

if what you want its not on a website that you created but that you want click on a button of a website, I suggest GreaseMonkey(firefox) or Tampermonkey(chrome). they can be use if you want to create something for manipulate a website without IDE.